# Create Command Line Tool with XCode 9+

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am learning Objective-C and using this [tutorial](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objectivec-lesson-1-hello-world/41). It says I am supposed to create a `Command Line Tool`. However, the XCode version in the tutorial is rather old. Pressing `CMD + N` does not reveal a Command Line Tool option. How can I write Objective-C and compile and run it in XCode 9.2?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Update your question with the version of Xcode you're using. You should also post a screenshot of the New Project Assistant when you choose File > New > Project. What are the available Mac app templates you see? Supplying that information is the only way you're going to get a more helpful answer than Vikram Singh's answer.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk as the title says its XCode 9+. To be precise, 9.2. I added the screenshot.

Comment: You selected iOS at the top so your screenshot is showing iOS templates. You have to click macOS at the top to see the command-line tool project template.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look @Stophface

If you are on mac then it says you should press cmd+shift+N
try it

[image: Under Mac Os Option]
[image: Create new Mac Os Project and you will find a option]

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the iOS category at the top, click on macOS and it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

this question is several months old, but for other people here is an answer :
You need to download an additional element : "Command line tools for Xcode"
link : https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
You need to create a free account, just with your email.
There are several versions, check which version of Xcode you have. Once it's installed if you click on "new project" you will have access to "command line" options