# How do I fix the permission denied in the terminal from XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

Im in a C++ class and I have to use XCode, I saved the .cpp to my desktop and I know how to find it in terminal but every time i try to convert it to .exe is says permissions denied. I already tried going into Get Info and unlocking the file but even still it doesn't work.

Last login: Mon Aug 31 18:02:48 on ttys001
quadeerajones@Quadeeras-Air ~ % /Users/quadeerajones/Desktop/CSC/Projects/Hello\ World/CPP/HW.cpp
zsh: permission denied: /Users/quadeerajones/Desktop/CSC/Projects/Hello World/CPP/HW.cpp
quadeerajones@Quadeeras-Air ~ %

Comment: You can't just *execute* a `.cpp` file, you must *compile* it. When compiled it will have a different filename and that file will be by default set executable.

Comment: If you're using XCode you should be able to start with a "Command Line Tool" template and build from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Command Line Tool with XCode 9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173097/create-command-line-tool-with-xcode-9)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling simple Hello World program on OS X via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073289/compiling-simple-hello-world-program-on-os-x-via-command-line)